# google app engine gwt application doesnt load with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, dns

I have deployed my app on google app engine [here is the link](http://hawt-project.appspot.com/MainEntry.html)

Than I have done all the stuff to create custom domain [link to my app with custom domain](http://hawt-project.hawtcorn.com/MainEntry.html)

Obviously the static data from app is loaded without the gwt module

(Right now no data is inserted in highly replicated Datastore for sake of simplicity)

Comment: I think,Your problem is something wrong with **GWT** not **App Engine**

Comment: All seems to load ok now.

Comment: Yeah i know it is something wrong with the gwt. (sorry about that I should added gwt tag earlier). Still gwt module doesnt load from my custom domain.

Comment: I think judging by the log that the problem is it doesnt actually "GET" the *.nocache.js file from where the magic of gwt is supposed coming from. When i query from the google domain it is loaded when is from custom it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an Gae issue but a Gwt issue. By the way - on my browser (Chrome 27) both domains work and the Gwt client is loaded. Without having any knowledge about your Gwt app it is really hard to debug.

There is one issue however:
http://hawt-project.appspot.com/hawtproject/hawtproject.nocache.js
has cache headers. And this might cause your browser to load an old version of your application. And this might cause your page to look broken. It would also explain why it works for me - and not for you.

Try to clean your browser cache and reload your page. If it works => Adjust Gae's static file cache settings in appengine-web.xml (If it's Java) - well you should do that anyway - caching nocache.js is just wrong.

Comment: Cant believe this, I was so obsessed to find the solution of the problem programmatically, didnt even try to load the page at the office, always tried from the home machine. Thanks.